# Why can't I delete the MutatingWebhookConfiguration I created?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm experimenting with mutating admission controllers, and I seem to be able to create one, but not delete it, why is this?

Creating webhook config:

```
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: MutatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  name: webhook
webhooks:
  - name: webhook.test.com
    clientConfig:
      service:
        name: my-service
        namespace: my-role
        path: "/foo"
      caBundle: "XXX"
    rules:
      - operations: ["CREATE", "UPDATE"]
        apiGroups: ["*"]
        apiVersions: ["*"]
        resources: ["pods"]
        scope:       "Namespaced"
    failurePolicy: Fail
```

Attempting to delete it: `kubectl delete MutatingingWebhookConfiguration webhook`
Response: `error: the server doesn't have a resource type "MutatingingWebhookConfiguration"`

I believe that error often has to do with the different versions of different resources, but I don't see why I would be able to create but not delete.

Comment: Can you execute `kubectl api-resources` and check if there is a line with `mutatingwebhookconfigurations`?

Comment: there is, looks like `mutatingwebhookconfigurations                  admissionregistration.k8s.io   false        MutatingWebhookConfiguration`

Comment: What version of k8s is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a silly mistake, I forgot to lowercase the resource name when using Kubectl, so `kubectl delete mutatingwebhookconfiguration webhook` works just fine.